# maximum number of iterations (maxIter = 50) reached without convergence

Tags: non-linear-regression

I am using R to conduct non-linear mixed effect model analysis. I have 23 groups data, each group has 5 points, and in my model, there are four parameters. My code is below

```
> model<-nlme(un~Johnson(Temp,mu0,Ea,dED,Topt),
fixed=list(mu0~1,Ea~1,dED~1,Topt~1),random=mu0+Ea+dED+Topt~1|id,
data=dilution2,
start=c(mu0=1,Ea=0.6,dED=0.5,Topt=20))
```

but it end up with errors[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeLnS.png)

even I set the maxIter by nlmeControl().
please help me solve this problem. thanks very much.